# Assistance with PS Script- Trying to create a folder with todays date on a networkshare and copy files to it from 2 different locations

Tags: network-programming, powershell-4.0, copy-item

I am trying to:
A. copy the current application event log from server A
B. copy the current IIS logs from server A
c. create  a folder with todays date on the network share and copy A and B above into it.
Currently I am using two commands in the script to copy the files required but I cannot figure out the create folder date and integrate that into the process...
Here is what I am using:

`your text`#Copies Application Event Log Folder to share
`your text`#Copy-Item -Path "\windowsserver\c$\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\application.evtx" -Destination `your text`"\networkshare\folder" -whatif

`your text`#Copies IIS logs with todays date to share
`your text`$RemotePath = "\servername\d$\LogFiles\W3SVC1"
`your text`$LocalPath = "\networkshare\folder""
`your text`$Max_days = "-1"
`your text`#Max_mins = "-5"
`your text`$Curr_date = get-date

`your text`#Checking date and then copying file from RemotePath to LocalPath, which would be the share
`your text`Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $RemotePath))
`your text`{
`your text`   if($file.LastWriteTime -gt ($Curr_date).adddays($Max_days))
`your text`    {

`your text`#         Copy-Item -Force -Path $file.fullname -Destination $LocalPath -WhatIf
`your text`        Copy-Item -Force -Path $file.fullname -Destination $LocalPath
`your text`#        Move-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $LocalPath
`your text`    }
`your text`    ELSE
`your text`    {"not copying $file"
`your text`    }

`your text`}

I got this to work this afternoon. Certainly not pretty, but...

```
 $basedir = "networkshare\report"
 $today   = (Get-Date).ToString('MM_dd_yy')

 $location = New-Item -Path $basedir -Type Directory -Name $today

 Copy-Item 
 '\\windowsserver\c$\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\application.evtx' - 
 Destination $location

 $EarliestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date     # 12AM 
 yesterday
 $LatestModifiedTime = (Get-Date).Date                   # 12AM today
 Get-ChildItem "\\windowsserver\d$\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.*" -File |
 ForEach-Object {
    if ( ($_.CreationTime -ge $EarliestModifiedTime) -and 
 ($_.CreationTime -lt $LatestModifiedTime) ){   # i.e., all day 
 yesterday
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination $location
        Write-Host "Copied $_"
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Not copying $_"
    }
 }
```

Your assistance and input is greatly appreciated.
Tony

I tried several different things from doing the good ole google search. I could create a folder with todays date in the destination, but could not figure out how to use that to get both A and B into there.
My brain is not wired for for this somehow...

Comment: Here is what I got to work so far, certainly not pretty, but ...

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the question.

Comment: Is there a more efficient way to do this with less code? copying the application event log is easy. copying the current IIS logs from a server to that folder with today's date is what gets me...